# SQL Server : IF statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I can't seem to get the IF statement to work in my WHERE clause for SQL Server.

Basically, if `@PK` is 0, I want to skip those two lines in the IF statement.

Here is what I have:

```
WHERE
    IF (@PK <> 0)
        pk.ID >= @PK
       AND pk.ID < (@PK + 500)
    ELSE
       Set_No = Set_No
    END
    AND Set_No IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Also tried:

```
WHERE
    CASE WHEN @PK <> 0
         pk.ID >= @PK
         AND pk.ID < (@PK + 500)
       ELSE
         Set_No = Set_No
    END
    AND Set_No IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Edit: I searched SO and tried several things I found (including above), but they didn't work.

Comment: `Set_No = Set_No` would be a tautology except for the case of `null` values. I suspect that's not a snag here though I still feel like pointing it out. Any reason you chose that over just `1=1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the logic you want is more easily written using basic boolean logic operators:

```
WHERE (@PK = 0 OR (pk.ID >= @PK AND pk.ID < @PK + 500)) AND
      Set_No IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```